# Problem with rotated yticklabels using pgfplot

Tags: latex

I am using `"yticklabel style={rotate=90}"` to rotate the ytick labels in a pgfplot by 90°. The text of the labels is not properly horizontally aligned.

In the following example "Grouped" is not aligned with the other labels (especially, because it contains a "p").

Image :

[image]

I am running out of "style" options to fix this, any idea how to get these values horizontally aligned? Thanks!

Edit:

Minimal example (please note, that my actual code uses labels to address columns in CSV files):

```
\documentclass{article}
% translate with >> pdflatex -shell-escape <file>

% This file is an extract of the PGFPLOTS manual, copyright by Christian Feuersaenger.
% 
% Feel free to use it as long as you cite the pgfplots manual properly.
%
% See
%   http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf
% for the complete manual.
%
% Any required input files (for <plot table> or <plot file> or the table package) can be downloaded
% at
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/
% and
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/plotdata/

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar, xmin=0,
    width=12cm, height=5.5cm, enlarge y limits=0.5,
    xlabel={\#participants},
    symbolic y coords={Flat,Grouped},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    yticklabel style={rotate=90},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(3,Flat) (7,Grouped)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might help to insert `\strut` in the labels without descending letters, but this is just a guess as long as there is no example code to test

Answer (score 1):

With `yticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=base,yshift=0.2cm}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar, xmin=0,
    width=12cm, height=5.5cm, enlarge y limits=0.5,
    xlabel={\#participants},
    symbolic y coords={Flat,Grouped},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    yticklabel style={rotate=90,anchor=base,yshift=0.2cm},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(3,{Flat}) (7,Grouped)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(the red line is just to see that the baselines are aligned)

Comment: Sweet, I fixed the offset to the y axis using `yshift=1ex`. Thanks!